# R placing and scaling subplots / images

Tags: r, image, maps

I've prepared a plot and two zoom areas, but am having problems inserting the zooms in the space underneath.

This is the main plot with some white space before the legend to insert the zoom plots:

[image]

I first thought of using `subplot` from the `Hmisc` package, but couldn't work out how to scale the inserts down to 30%.

Another option might be to just import the png images of all plots and then use the `grid` package to scale and place them, but I haven't tried this yet.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide more detail about what the final plot should look like? It might also be helpful to provide a little bit of mock data.

Comment: I basically have three full sized plots (it doesn't really matter what kind of plots), what matters is that I want to overlay the other two plots, resized to about 30% on top of the first plot.

Comment: I've just noticed that the `grid` package has been archived - so that might not be an easy option anymore.

Comment: What package(s) are you using to do the plotting?

Comment: `rgdal` + `maptools` to load and plot the shapefiles. `ggplot2` can't cope with the islands around the Welsh coast when filling the shapes, so I'm just using the basic plotting options. (`RColorBrewer` for shadings, `classInt` for the groupings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have three plots - `I've prepared a plot and two zoom areas`

I was trying to quickly wrap up three pictures contains zoom relation.. but the whole idea is to show you how to use `viewport` to arrange several plots.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

data_x <- 5:10
data_y <- 6:11
a <- qplot(data_x, data_y, xlim=c(0, 15), ylim=c(0, 15), size=data_x)
b <- qplot(data_x, data_y, xlim=c(5, 10), ylim=c(5, 10), size=data_x) + theme(legend.position="none")
c <- qplot(data_y, data_y, xlim=c(7.5, 9.5), ylim=c(7.5, 10.5),  size=data_x) + theme(legend.position="none")

vpb <- viewport(width = 0.3, 
                height = 0.3, 
                x = 0.3, 
                y = 0.8)

vpc <- viewport(width = 0.3, 
                height = 0.3, 
                x = 0.6, 
                y = 0.3)

# print and overlap
print(a)
print(b, vp = vpb)
print(c, vp = vpc)
```

[image]

Comment: This looks great, a shame that the `grid` package has been archived. Looks like it's a right nightmare trying to install it from source under Windows!

Comment: Although the `grid` package has been archived it seem to be available under R Studio! HURRAY.

Comment: @JoanneDemmler If so, can you mark this question as being answered so people knows this case has been completed. :)